# Output of Python interpreter?

Tags: python, class, object, interpreter

When using the Python interpreter, just writing

```
3+4
```

causes it to print '7'

But when importing some class ('Something', which has its own **str** and **add** implemented) and do this:

```
a=Something(var2)
b=Something(var2)
a+b
```

the interpreter just prints a message reporting the action (EDIT: by this, I meant the message class.Something object at 0xspam..., which is the output of **repr** when it's not actually implemented, when I thought I'd get something like the output of **str**), it doesn't prints the str version of the new object that was just created

Why does this happen? How can it be changed?

EDIT:
The problem had to do with confusion over what **str** and **repr** do (I didn't know about that **repr** existed when I asked the question), I thought it was enough for a class to have **str** implemented to both being able to obtain a string from an object, and being able to print it directly to the interpreter without having to write 'print'. But the latter is something that's actually done by implementing **repr** appropiately

Comment: What is "a message reporting the action"? Normally, the interpreter doesn't print any such thing. It only prints prompts, the repr of your results, and the traceback of your exceptions.

Comment: by "a message reporting the action" I meant the results of repr, but I didn't know about repr until now, which is what answered my initial question. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dup, but you should definitely read [Difference between str and repr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python/2626364#2626364), the canonical question on `repr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class with its own `add` implemented:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.x + other.x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s with x=%s" % (self.__class__, self.x)
```

Now, let's create some instances and add them:

```
>>> a = A(3); b = A(2)
>>> a + b
<class 't.A'> with x=5
```

Yes, it prints.

Without the custom `__repr__` as defined above, what prints would be the usual default representation, such as:

```
<t.A object at 0x7f7d7bc9f990>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I wanted, I knew there had to be some function I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the rules the interpreter uses:

For anything but an expression statement, nothing is printed.

For an expression statement, the result is assigned to `_`, then the equivalent of this code happens:

```
if _ is not None:
    try:
        print(repr(_))
    except Exception as e:
        print(<some message with e and object.__repr__(_)>)
```

That's really all there is to it.

So, if nothing at all is getting printed, the most likely possibility is that `a+b` returns `None` here. For example, that `Something.__add__` that you forgot to show us could look like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    tmp = copy.copy(self)
    tmp += other
    # oops, no return tmp
```

Or maybe `a+b` returns an object whose `repr` is the empty string, or all whitespace, and you didn't notice that it printed a blank line.

If something *is* getting printed, but it's not what you expected, then probably the `__repr__` isn't defined the way you expected. Since you only mention defining `__str__`, you may not realize that `__repr__` is a separate function, and if you just inherit the default, it tends to look like `<__main__.Spam at 0x115f018d0>`.

Comment: @Jumpingcat: In that case, I think John1024's answer may be more of a direct solution. But please, edit your question so we don't have to guess exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it then, I wasn't quite sure about how to word my question.

Comment: @Jumpingcat: No, don't edit it to say "solved", edit it to answer the questions you were asked. Show us exactly what you typed and what output you got, instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: sorry again! I described it now, I hope it's ok.

Comment: @Jumpingcat Stackoverflow has customs that are a bit different from elsewhere.  If you want to understand better, it may help to read: ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

`print a+b` instead of just `a+b`, of course

As to why `a+b` doesn't cause str() to be called on objects, I don't know.

Comment: sure, I know how to do it, but I was asking about why is it different for both of those objects.